# How to load a second user log in form?

Tags: 7, users, forms, hooks

I have used default user login block on top navigation. I need to load another log in form on some pages.

I am trying to load the form by

```
drupal_get_form('user-login')
```

I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: user-login in drupal_retrieve_form() (line
>   763 of /path/to/drupal/includes/form.inc). Warning:
>   call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   function 'user-login' not found or invalid function name in
>   drupal_retrieve_form() (line 798 of
>   /path/to/drupal/includes/form.inc).

Is it possible to load a second log in form? (Drupal 7)

Comment: Do you mean you want two log-in blocks/forms on the same page?

Comment: Yes, One is on top navigation on all pages. Second one will be on some pages where there is a password protected content.

Comment: You can use the LoginToboggan module if you want to show a login form when users do not have appropriate permission.  Just check the setting for "show login form on access denied."  http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point in the error message is:

> ...expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'user-login' not
>   found

You need to use:

```
drupal_get_form('user_login');
```

Where [user_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login/7) is the form builder function in this case.

e.g:

```
print render(drupal_get_form('user_login'));
```